# Lists in Python - Each array in different row

Tags: python, list

how can I create a new list with the following format.

The 3 arrays inside each row should be in different rows.

```
a= [['111,0.0,1', '111,1.27,2', '111,3.47,3'],
    ['222,0.0,1', '222,1.27,2', '222,3.47,3'],
    ['33,0.0,1', '33,1.27,2', '33,3.47,3'],
    ['44,0.0,1', '44,1.27,2', '4,3.47,3'],
    ['55,0.0,1', '55,1.27,2', '55,3.47,3']]
```

Final desired ouput:

```
 b=[['111,0.0,1', 
  '111,1.27,2', 
  '111,3.47,3',
  '222,0.0,1', 
  '222,1.27,2', 
  '222,3.47,3',
  '33,0.0,1', 
  '33,1.27,2', 
  '33,3.47,3',
  '44,0.0,1',
  '44,1.27,2',
  '44,3.47,3',
  '55,0.0,1', 
  '55,1.27,2', 
  '55,3.47,3']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
b = [[j for i in a for j in i]]
```

Comment: oh yeah! thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, there is no concept of rows vs. columns in Python. Your end result is just a big list of `str`'s, within another list.

You can create the big list by chaining all of the original small lists together (`a[0] + a[1] + ...`), for which we may use

```
import itertools
big_list = list(itertools.chain(*a))
```

To put this inside another list,

```
b = [big_list]
```